# How to play a sound file specified by user with playsound()?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

How to play a sound file specified by user in an array using the PlaySound()? I'm using Windows7 and VC++ 2010.

Suppose I use the **gets(song);** statement to input the complete path of the song from user.

Comment: Did you try anything or look at the documentation?

Comment: PlaySound(TEXT("songname.wav"),NULL,SND_ASYNC); this works but I require the user to enter the file name and then play it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx

```
PlaySound( song, NULL, SND_FILENAME );
```

Comment: ERROR: argument of type char* is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"

Comment: @user2151923 that means your **real** problem is in converting from `char*` to `WCHAR*`.  You chose the former, and `PlaySound` + your project settings expects strings to be the latter.

Comment: Well thanks!..Finally got it. Just converted the 'song' variable to wchar and PlaySound() works!